# nested while loop in python tkinter

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, while-loop

The following code searches a text file for a name and displays the related number in a tkinter entry box in Python.

so original text file includes:

```
bob 19
dan 20
shayne 17
```

I would like add another nested loop so that if there are two names the same then two numbers are returned to the entry box. Sorry, I am new to Python, have tried but always come up with an error.

```
bob 18
bob 19
dan 20
shayne 17
```

```
#https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lR90cp1wQ1I

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

race = []

def displayInfo(race, name):
    found = False
    pos = 0
    while pos < len(race) and not found:
        if race[pos][0] == name: 
            found = True
        pos+=1 
    if found:
        return race[pos-1][1]   
    else:
        messagebox.showerror(message = "Invalid input, please try again.")

def clickArea():
    fin.set(displayInfo(race, name.get()))

def createlist():
    raceFile = open ("C:/python/files/number_list.txt", 'r')
    for line in raceFile:
        racer = line.split()
        race.append(racer)
    raceFile.close()
    return race

root = Tk()
root.title("Read From text File/List GUI")

Label(root, text="Name").grid(row=0, column=0)
name = StringVar()
Entry(root, textvariable=name).grid(row=0, column =1)

Label(root, text="Finish Time").grid(row=2, column=0)
fin=IntVar()
Label(root, textvariable=fin).grid(row=2, column=1)

button = Button(root, text="Finish Time", command=clickArea)
button.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)

createlist()
print(race)
```

Answer (score 1):

your question is not related to tkinter, so I made the code without it.

It works like this: you enter the name you're looking for, then it looks for matches using the count method. If there is a match, then the index is written to the 'B' array. Further, since there is a space between the name and number, we take the space index + 1 and start outputting the string from this position to the end.

```
name = input('who do you want to find: ') + " "


with open("number_list.txt", "r") as file:
    A = file.readlines()


#remove program entry '\n'   
for i in range(len(A)):
    A[i] = A[i].strip()


#getting matching names
B = [] #the court records the names we need
for i in A:
    if i.count(name): #truth check
    #this notation is equivalent to the notationsi: if i.count(name) == 1:
        B.append(i)

print('the following numbers match:')
for i in B:
    index_space = i.index(' ') + 1
    print(i[index_space:])
```

Comment: works exactly as described, +1. it will me a good start. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the values for a name, you need to go through all the items in `race`:

```py
def displayInfo(race, name):
    # go through the race list and return values for given name
    found = [x[1] for x in race if x[0] == name]
    if found:
        # return the values separated by comma
        return ", ".join(found)
    # no item found for the given name
    return "not found"
```

Comment: Thanks ++.  this works well as per Original code.